# Digest mimatch for sha256

Tags: openssl, echo, sha256

I am trying to encode the string *`abc`* using sha256 and below is the output I got.

```
ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
```

But, if I use the command `openssl sha256 -hex` on Linux command line, I get the below output for the same string.

```
edeaaff3f1774ad2888673770c6d64097e391bc362d7d6fb34982ddf0efd18cb
```

Why is there a difference in the outputs?
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Try `echo -n`: `echo -n abc | openssl sha256 -hex`.