# Migrate Public/Private Keys from one programming language to other for Signing Payload and verifying them

Tags: java, scala, perl, signature, public-key

I have one Perl Script that sign the payload with private key(id_rsa), generated in linux machine with SSH-Keygen or OpenSSL. After that I am taking the hash or the signed value, decoding it in base 64 and sending to my scala code. Here I send two things, the public key(id_rsa.pub) and the encoded signature.

Now when I verify the signature it always give me false result.
I have tried the opposite, like singing in Scala and verifying with Perl. It returned me false.
I generated the keys in Scala and put them in Linux and done the signing and verifying part from Perl. It worked. It even worked when I imported both keys in scala and try to do the signing and verifying part both from scala.

But whenever I am mixing up these two like signing in Perl and verifying in Scala or signing in Scala and verifying in Perl, it is giving me a false result.

My question is is there any common format that I can use here. The code I am using is -

```
val fileOpened = Source.fromFile("file.hash") // taking the hashed value
  val payload = fileOpened.getLines.mkString //file contents as string
  val decodedString = Base64.getDecoder.decode(payload.getBytes) // Base64 Decoding of the hashed value
  println("decodedString, the hash value was base64 encoded, so decoded it and took into bytes")
  println(decodedString) //the hash value was base64 encoded, so decoded it and took into bytes

  val fileOpened1 = Source.fromFile("file")
  val ComareElement = fileOpened1.getLines.mkString
  val decodedString1 = new String(ComareElement).getBytes
  println("decodedString1,  this is the main payload to compare, turned into bytes")
  println(decodedString1) // this is the main payload to compare, turned into bytes

  //val keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA") //Creating KeyPair generator object
  //keyPairGen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom) //Initializing the key pair generator
  //val pair: KeyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair

  // save public key as id_rsa.pub
  //val x509keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pair.getPublic.getEncoded)
  //val publicKeyStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\MyWorkSpace\\PayLoadSign\\src\\main\\scala\\id_rsa.pub")
  //publicKeyStream.write(x509keySpec.getEncoded)

  // save private key as id_rsa
  //val pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pair.getPrivate.getEncoded)
  //val privateKeyStream = new FileOutputStream("id_rsa")
  //privateKeyStream.write(pkcs8KeySpec.getEncoded)

  val filePublicKey = new File("id_rsa.pub")
  var inputStream = new FileInputStream("id_rsa.pub")
  val encodedPublicKey: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](filePublicKey.length.toInt)
  inputStream.read(encodedPublicKey)
  inputStream.close()

  val filePrivateKey = new File("id_rsa")
  inputStream = new FileInputStream("id_rsa")
  val encodedPrivateKey: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](filePrivateKey.length.toInt)
  println("The key is now " +encodedPrivateKey)
  inputStream.read(encodedPrivateKey)
  inputStream.close()

  val keyFactory: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

  // public key
  val publicKeySpec: X509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedPublicKey)
  val publicKey: PublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)

  // private key
  val privateKeySpec: PKCS8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey)
  val privateKey: PrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec)

  new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey)

  // val pair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair //Generate the pair of keys
  //val privKey = pair.getPrivate //Getting the privatekey from the key pair
  //val pubKey = pair.getPublic  //Getting the PublicKey from the key pair
  val privKey = privateKey //Getting the privatekey from the key pair
  val pubKey = publicKey  //Getting the PublicKey from the key pair
  println("Getting the privateKey from the key pair " + privateKey)
  println("Getting the publicKey from the key pair " + publicKey)

  var writer = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\MyWorkSpace\\PayLoadSign\\src\\main\\scala\\Private_Key"))
  writer.write(privKey.toString)
  writer.close()
  writer = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\MyWorkSpace\\PayLoadSign\\src\\main\\scala\\Public_Key"))
  writer.write(pubKey.toString)
  writer.close()

  val sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA") //Creating a Signature object
  //sign.initSign(privKey)
  //val bytes = payload.getBytes //Initializing the signature
  val bytes = decodedString
  println(bytes)
  //sign.update(bytes) //Adding data to the signature
  //val signature = sign.sign //Calculating the signature
  //val signedPayload = new BASE64Encoder().encode(signature)
  //writer = new PrintWriter(new File("file.hash"))
  //writer.write(signedPayload)
  //writer.close()

  println(bytes)
  sign.initVerify(pubKey)  //Initializing the signature
  sign.update(bytes)
  //println(signature)
  //val bool = sign.verify(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(signedPayload)) //Verifying the signature
  //println(sign.verify(signature))
  val bool = sign.verify(bytes)
  println(bool)
  if (bool) System.out.println("Signature verified")
  else System.out.println("Signature failed")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. I achieved that by correcting the signature algorithm and its default values in Perl. Also you have to take care of the new line characters (\n). The modified code for verification should look like this in Scala -

```
    object Verify_Test extends App {


  var privateKeyString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("private_key.pem")), Charset.defaultCharset)
  privateKeyString = privateKeyString.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")

  var publicKeyString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("public_key.pem")), Charset.defaultCharset)
  publicKeyString = publicKeyString.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")

  val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

  val encodedPrivateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyString))
  val privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(encodedPrivateKeySpec)

  val encodedPublicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyString))
  val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(encodedPublicKeySpec)

  var encodedSignatureVale = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("hashedSignature")), Charset.defaultCharset)
  encodedSignatureVale = encodedSignatureVale.replaceAll("\\n", "")
  println(encodedSignatureVale)

  var actualValue = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("original data")), Charset.defaultCharset)
  //actualValue = actualValue.replaceAll("\\n", "")
  println(actualValue)

  val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
  //signature.initSign(privateKey)
  //signature.update("Hello, World\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))
  //val signatureValue = signature.sign
  //val encodedSignatureVale = Base64.encodeBase64String(signatureValue)
  //println(Base64.encodeBase64String(signatureValue))


  signature.initVerify(publicKey)
  // signature.update("Hello, World\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))
  signature.update(actualValue.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  val bool = signature.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedSignatureVale))
  println(bool)
  if (bool) println("Signature verified")
  else println("Signature failed")}
```

Remember I have taken both private and public key here. But we can use only public for verification.

The Perl code for signing will be -

```
use File::Slurp   qw(read_file);
use File::Slurp   qw(write_file);
use MIME::Base64  qw(encode_base64);
require Crypt::PK::RSA;
my $datatosign = read_file( 'payload.txt');
my $privatekey = Crypt::PK::RSA->new('private_key.pem');

my $signature = $privatekey->rsa_sign_message($datatosign, 'SHA256', 'v1.5');
my $hash = encode_base64($signature, '');
write_file('payload.hash', $hash);
```

Comment: The url that saved me is ----  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094412/openssl-and-java-yield-different-sha256-rsa-signatures